# Kanban option not visible in 'Select List View' menu

Tags: list-view, kanban

Using Service Cloud and have created an app for change requests. I am using the Change Request object and am attempting to create a list view with a Kanban view, however, I only see the option for 'Table' or 'Split View'.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you check your org edition: Essentials, Group, Professional, Enterprise, Performance, Unlimited, and Developer Editions and also check if you have [permission](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.kanban_use.htm&type=5).